# Object with abstract member(without pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have the following class,

```
class Simulation {
public:
  btDefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration;
  btBroadphaseInterface broadphase;
  btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver;
  btDynamicsWorld dynamicsWorld;

  Simulation() {
    broadphase = btCollisionDispatcher(&collisionConfiguration);
  }
}
```

and when I compile I get this error

```
cannot declare field ‘Simulation::broadphase’ to be of abstract type ‘btBroadphaseInterface’
```

Now I think I know what I did wrong.  If this compiled then the moment I called the constructor the memory allocated would be for a virtual class and wouldn't contain the subclass(btCollisionDispatcher).  I know how to solve this with pointers, but I've been hearing from people that you should advoid pointers in C++ and I thought I would give it a try.  I've been successful so far but I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Well, what do you want to achieve?  You cannot have a value member that's pure-virtual (abstract).  You can either use a reference, or a pointer, or use a smart-pointer.

Comment: If someone told you "avoid pointers, period", you can safely ignore that person's advice on all future matters concerning C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can only have pointers or references to abstract classes because you can't instantiate an abstract class because, by definition, it has an "incomplete" definition (not to be taken literally). It's just an interface.

If you want to avoid pointers, you can use references, like this:

```
class Simulation {
public:
  btDefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration;
  btBroadphaseInterface& broadphase;
  btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver;
  btDynamicsWorld dynamicsWorld;

  Simulation() : broadphase(someFunctionThatReturnsAbtBroadphaseInterfaceReference()) {

  }
}
```

Or smart pointers, like this:

```
// header for shared_ptr
#include <memory>

class Simulation {
public:
  btDefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration;
  shared_ptr<btBroadphaseInterface> broadphase;
  btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver;
  btDynamicsWorld dynamicsWorld;

  Simulation() : broadphase(someFunctionThatReturnsAbtBroadphaseInterfacePointerOrSmartPointer()) {

  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the second example needs to return a *pointer* or *smart pointer*.  If it returns a raw pointer, one needs to be very careful about ownership issues.

Comment: @Oli yeah, just noticed that, fixed the function name.

Comment: Why `shared_ptr` **always**? I am all pro- smart pointers, but if ownership is not shared, there are other solutions like `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (depending on what standard your compiler supports)

Comment: @David I never said always. I used shared ptr here so he wouldn't go insane when he copies an object.

Comment: @Seth: The **always** is not because you said it, but **all** the answers where a smart pointer is suggested they default to `shared_ptr`, and that is not a good choice, exactly because of your last comment: If you have `shared_ptr` you probably have `unique_ptr`, and if you choose that one, it will fail to copy and provide a compile error, rather than silently *sharing* the object and making you wonder why the contents of one object mysteriously change when you are not accessing it...

Comment: @David This is the first answer where I've suggested using shared_ptr rather than auto_ptr. Also, you won't wonder why the contents of one object are mysteriously changing when you change another object, because that's what pointers do anyways. It's the expected behaviour as opposed to auto_ptr which magically deletes its object from under you when you make a copy.

Comment: Also, I don't get a compile error when I copy an object with an auto_ptr. It would be a runtime error.

Comment: @Seth: You will get an error if you use `std::unique_ptr`, as ownership is *unique*. If you have `shared_ptr`, then you probably have `unique_ptr`. The case of `auto_ptr` is a little weirder because of the *implicit move semantics*, which means that you have to be careful with it, but at any rate it does not impose the additional (unneeded) costs of `shared_ptr`. At any rate, I insist, the rant is not because of this particular answer or you, but because it has become usual to find `shared_ptr` as a *one size fits all* solution for resource management.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your implementation of the class you are already fixing the type, why not just store a variable of the actual type to be used?

```
class Simulation {
public:
  btDefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration;
  btCollisionDispatcher broadphase;

  Simulation() : broadphase(&collisionConfiguration) {
  }
};
```

Note that the code above is correct, but may be prone to error as one member depends for initialization on a different member, be sure not to reorder the declarations in the class.

If, on the other hand, the actual type to be used is not to be hardcoded, then you will need to pass a pointer or reference (and ensure that lifetimes of the different objects is correct).

Comment: You can probably ensure that they're initialised in the right order by doing `Simulation() : collisionConfiguration(), broadphase(&collisionConfiguration) { }`

Comment: @Seth: The order of initialization is that of the member declaration in the class, not that of the code in the initialization list, so the comment stands: it is fragile because the order is defined somewhere else in the code separate from where the initialization is performed.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem in using pointers.

At least while you use some libraries you should try to do the things in the way they think of them.

The best way to do what you mean is actually using them.

Don't worry about them.